# Failed to initialize FBO on Android SDK emulator device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

So this is how FBO is initialized:

```
/**
 * Initializes Renderbuffer.
 */
static GLuint init_renderbuffer(GLuint width, GLuint height, GLenum format) {
    GLuint renderbuffer;

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("init_renderbuffer: glGenRenderbuffers");

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);
    checkGlError("init_renderbuffer: glBindRenderbuffer");

    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, format, width, height);
    checkGlError("init_renderbuffer: glRenderbufferStorage");

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    checkGlError("init_renderbuffer: glBindRenderbuffer");

    return renderbuffer;
}

/**
 * Initializes FBO.
 */
static void engine_init_fbo(struct engine* engine, GLuint width, GLuint height) {
    // create renderable texture
    glGenTextures(1, &engine->renderableTexture);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glGenTextures");

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->renderableTexture);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glBindTexture");

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 0);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glTexImage2D");

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glTexParameteri");

    // create render buffers
    engine->depthRenderBuffer   = init_renderbuffer(width, height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16);
    engine->stencilRenderBuffer = init_renderbuffer(width, height, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8);

    LOGI("****************************** FBO: T: %d, D: %d, S: %d", engine->renderableTexture,
         engine->depthRenderBuffer, engine->stencilRenderBuffer);

    // create framebuffer object
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &engine->framebufferObject);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glGenFramebuffers");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, engine->framebufferObject);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glBindFramebuffer");

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, engine->renderableTexture, 0);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glFramebufferTexture2D");

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, engine->depthRenderBuffer);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, engine->stencilRenderBuffer);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glCheckFramebufferStatus");

    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        switch(status) {
            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
                LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: FBO error: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT");
                break;

            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
                LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: FBO error: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT");
                break;

            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS:
                LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: FBO error: FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS");
                break;

            case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
                LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: FBO error: FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED");
                break;

            default:
                LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: Unknown FBO error");
        }
    }
    else {
        LOGI("****************************** engine_init_fbo: FBO has been successfully initialized");
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glBindTexture");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    checkGlError("engine_init_fbo: glBindFramebuffer");
}
```

As you can see, everything here is done according to OpenGL ES standard: 2D texture with RGB565 internal format is used as color; 2 renderbuffers are used as depth and stencil surfaces; dimensions are 32x32.

It works fine on real device (Alcatel OT 918D, prints "FBO has been successfully initialized" in adb logcat), but fails with FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED on virtual device.

My virtual device's CPU is atom, GPU emulation is enabled, OpenGL ES 2.0 works fine - checked with another applications (which do not use FBOs).

Entire project (based on native-activity sample from NDK), which can be compiled with ndk-build, is here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byy41LxMuTKUZVJxSUtBZDVDXzA/edit?usp=sharing

My question is: Is this a bug in android-sdk emulator? Because everything seems to meet the minimum requerements to the OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Found the solution. It appears, that AVD does not support this configuration of attached objects. I had to remove stencil attachment to make it work.

EDIT2:
It appears to be the context creation problem. I did not require stencil bits, so probably AVD created context without stencil support, and Alcatel phone - with stencil.

Anyway, this is not a bug, but my mistake.